# Make EXT grid editable

Tags: extjs

I have requirement with the following functionality in EXTJS version 3.0

Is there any option of having the grid which is editable. Each record is editable. Like i need grid as excel document.Which i need to show for bulk add and edit the grid

,i need modified records for the above grid to save the records and optional is do validations on any column

and i want to add button as Add page which will add 20 empty editable rows at the end of the grid. Pagination should work properly.

If any one knows please help me...critical prioritized work

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please make your title self-describing and not dependent on the body of the question.

Comment: I think it will help you.

Follow this code for [Row Editing of a grid layout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930982/is-it-possible-to-show-more-than-one-summary-row-in-gridpanel-of-extjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although 3.0 is no longer supported by Sencha as far as I know, there is a cell editor in the library that you can use to edit individual cells.

The button to add rows you are going to have to code yourself, but it should not be difficult.

Comment: thank you for your answer achieved this and i want to add an auto suggestion for one of the grid column,so that an auto suggestion box should show on entering 3 characters with remaining fields as well below is the example i have 4 columns in grid lets take column1 column2 column3 and column4. upon entering 3 characters in column1,since my grid is editable an auto suggestion box will open with column1,column2,column3 and column4 matching records (sever side like search on column1)

Comment: you need to use combobox component for that. refer to the docs and examples of this. Also if you find answer useful please click the  hollow checkmark to accept the answer and click the up arrow to mark as useful.

Comment: thank you dbrin yes you are right but its not full filling my requirement i need custom component for this am i expecting more? if you have any idea please share thanks in advance!!!

Comment: everything yo described combobox supports